# How to create a public key file in gpg from a given public key

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg, public-key

A colleague of mine gave me their public key in text format and now I want to use that public key to encrypt my plain messages.

The thing is, I don't know how to create a key for an existing public key. As in how do I import the public key in `GnuPG` if I only have the public key in an email message? Like I know how to generate a random new key, just now how to create or import a public key

This is the public key given to me:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: OpenPGP.js v3.0.9
Comment: https://openpgpjs.org
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=jHTx
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Once imported, would I encrypt my plaintext in the following manner:

```
echo "New to the game" | gpg -e -r recipient_userid textfile
```

I know it may seem easy to some, but it has been driving me mad only because I don't know how to create a file which has my colleagues public key in it

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid OpenPGP key file. Just store it into a text file (using a proper text editor which does not "fiddle" with the characters or newlines, so MS Office or Libreoffice do not qualify here) and rund `gpg --import <path-to-keyfile>`.

Usually the ASCII-armored keys (the base64-like copy you posted here) are stored with `.asc` extension, but this is not really important especially when working on the command line. If you want to import the key using a graphical user interface (by double clicking, ...) the extension might be important, though.